# phonegap/jquery mobile remote debugging? (android)

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I would like to debug my project on android remotely. How can I do that? I have build phonegap project that runs on android ant apache (i think) and I am building it with eclipse but just the logcat isnt anough. So I would like to know if there are any simple remote debuging programms?

Comment: Remote debugging Phonegap apps with Chrome Dev Tools: http://10typesofpeople.tumblr.com/post/76669066010/remote-debugging-phonegap-apps-with-chrome-dev-tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found anything apart this:
http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/

This is official phonegap debugging tool for apps build on their site. Try also:
[PhoneGap Debug Docs](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/phonegap-debug)

Again, this works on PhoneGap build builded app. But if you add a proper definition in head of your htmls, you are also able to use this tool with your Eclipse builded apps.

Try adding this:

```
<script stype="text/javascript" scr="phonegap.js"></script>
```

There is another one line to add. I can't rember it right now. I will update it later:P

Comment: I found that last time I was searching but I cant manage to find windows version.

Comment: It is java app (.jar file). It is multiplatform. Try to follow this: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/1.x/1.5.0/Installing.html and run this jar from console. You should easily find how to run .jar files with google.